# Unable to run Theano on Windows 7 with GPU

Tags: installation, gpu, theano, windows-7-x64

I have been trying to install Theano and run it on Windows 7. I have installed CUDA, CUDnn and the dependencies. Here is the content of my .theanorc file:

```
[global]
device=cuda
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

[nvcc]
fastmath = True

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0
[dnn]
include_path=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include
library_path=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64
```

I get the following error when I import theano:

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.

Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this error:

'In file included from C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v8.0\\include/driver_types.h:53:0,\r\n from C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v8.0\\include/cudnn.h:63,\r\n from C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\try_flags_c5tg_5jg.c:4:\r\nC:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v8.0\\include/host_defines.h:84:0: warning: "__cdecl" redefined\r\n #define __cdecl\r\n ^\r\n<built-in>: note:this is the location of the previous definition\r\nC:/Program Files/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:/Program: No such file or directory\r\nC:/Program Files/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find Files/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/default-manifest.o: No such file or directory\r\ncollect2.exe: error: l d returned 1 exit status\r\n' 

Mapped name None to device cuda: Quadro M2000 (0000:02:00.0)
```

Comment: yup I have the same problem